# How to launch the Android Download Manager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-download-manager

How do I start default phone's download manager, like the one builtin in default browser? I need to create an intent that contains url of file to download. I know it's possible, as I saw some applications doing it in the past.

Comment: I think you will see this related link usefull   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500515/how-to-use-built-in-download-manager-on-android

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9033224

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html).

Browsing the Android source code reveals that the default browser is using this as well.

**EDIT**

You can browse the source code for DownloadManager [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/app/DownloadManager.java) and try to use the code to make it work on 7. Bare in mind the dependencies of the class might also be not available on 7 (most probably) but it might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm limited to API level 7 and the feature you mentioned uses API level 9. Also the applications I saw were using API below 9 too.

Comment: It seems it was a private API before 9. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525204/android-download-intent

Comment: you can try to replicate the DownloadManager class. Look at my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

As easy as:

```
startActivity(new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS));
```

Comment: After writing the file, if i open the downloads folder programmatically using startActivity(Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS)). File is not visible. But if i open from file explorer of phone, then the file is visible. Any idea, why this is happening ?