# Android: where are downloaded files saved?

Tags: android, download

I am trying to develop a "document manager"

I have the necessity of accessing the files downloaded from the internet, from Gmail, for other mail clients, from other internet sources...

I would like to understand **where these files are stored exactly on Android:**

1- if there is an SD

2- if there is no SD Card

so that I can show them to the user in my App at any time.

Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Please review the android file system structure at http://www.stevesandroidguide.com/android-files/

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Download`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Most devices have some form of emulated storage. if they support sd cards they are usually mounted to `/sdcard` (or some variation of that name) which is usually symlinked to to a directory in `/storage` like `/storage/sdcard0` or `/storage/0`  sometimes the emulated storage is mounted to `/sdcard` and the actual path is something like /storage/emulated/legacy. You should be able to use  to get the downloads directory. You are best off using the api calls to get directories. 
`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);`

Since the filesystems and sdcard support varies among devices.

see similar question for more info [how to access downloads folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908193/how-to-access-downloads-folder-in-android)

Usually the DownloadManager handles downloads and the files are then accessed by requesting the file's uri fromthe download manager using a file id to get where file was places which would usually be somewhere in the sdcard/ real or emulated since apps can only read data from certain places on the filesystem outside of their data directory like the sdcard

Comment: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated. Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 30):

In my experience all the files which i have downloaded from `internet,gmail` are stored in

```
/sdcard/download
```

on `ics`

```
/sdcard/Download
```

You can access  it using

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```