# How to create a folder in Download directory (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like to create a directory in a Download directory (the one which stores all the files I download from web) so I can see it in browser after I plug the mobile into my PC.

```
File myDirectory = new File(dir, "NewDirectory");
```

What should be the value of dir?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383055/android-where-are-downloaded-files-saved

Answer (score 8):

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/your folder/");
dir.mkdirs(); // creates needed dirs
```

Don't forget to ask for permissions on Marshmallow or newer and to add the write storage permission to Android Manifest, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/4479004

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile() {

File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/DirName");

if (!direct.exists()) {
    File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Download/DirName/");
    wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, never use "/sdcard/" while creating files or directories..always use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). it gives the primary shared/external storage directory.